# Shortening a directory name relative to a base directory

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

In Bash, the directory `~` has a special status, since if the current directory resides in `~`, it automatically gets shortened. That is, `dirs +0` and the `\w` substitution atom in `PS1` shows

```
$ dirs +0
~/test/directory
```

Instead of `/home/myname/test/directory`.

Is it possible to grant another directory this special status? I often work in a source tree where the top level is `$DEV` or `$SRC`, and I would like to show the current directory in `PS1` as

```
$SRC/current/working/directory
```

instead of (for example)

```
~/projects/devel/source/current/working/directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $PS1 contains literal variable expansions, they will be lazily expanded every time the prompt is shown. So the direct, one-substitution-only, method is to use `${var/#search/replacement}` to swap one prefix for another:

```
PS1='\u@\h ${PWD/#"${SRC:-xxx}"/"\$SRC"} \$ '
```

Note how the assignment uses single-quotes, so the `${PWD...}` expansion is included verbatim, not expanded at assign time. (Lazy PS1 expansion is done by default in bash, but also possible in zsh if you know what option to enable. I don't.)

The usage of `${SRC:-xxx}` instead of just `$SRC` is a silly safeguard against $SRC being empty or unset, in which case you'd get the prefix everywhere instead of nowhere.

The slightly more complex method is to call a custom function and let it generate the desired output:

```
show_abbrevd_path() {
    # longest prefix should be first
    case $PWD in
        "$SRC/"*)  echo "${PWD/#"$SRC/"/"\$SRC/"}";;
        "$HOME/"*) echo "${PWD/#"$HOME/"/"~/"}";;
        *)         echo "$PWD";;
    esac
}

PS1='\u@\h $(show_abbrevd_path) \$ '
```

(Side not: The quotes in `"${PWD/#"$SRC/"/"\$SRC/"}"` are actually *nested* and not closed/reopened. ${…} is magic like that, despite SU's syntax highlighter thinking otherwise.)

Of course, it doesn't have to be a function – you could also use `$(pwd | sed ...)` or `$(perl ...)` or `$(~/bin/fancypwd)` – but the more processes you create, the longer it takes to display your prompt, and the shell *feels* slower as a result.

On that note, you could get the same effect with *zero* subprocesses by calling the function via $PROMPT_COMMAND and picking up its global state, thus avoiding the $(…) subshell:

```
make_abbrevd_path() {
    case $PWD in
        "$SRC/"*)  xpwd="${PWD/#"$SRC/"/"\$SRC/"}";;
        "$HOME/"*) xpwd="${PWD/#"$HOME/"/"~/"}";;
        *)         xpwd="$PWD";;
    esac
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='make_abbrevd_path'

PS1='\u@\h $xpwd \$ '
```